# Как добавить заголовки from в письмо с аттачем?

Tags: email, php, sendmail

```
// Вспомогательная функция для отправки почтового сообщения с вложением 
 function send_mail($to, $thm, $html, $path) 
{

$fp = fopen($path,"r"); 
if (!$fp)
{
print "Файл $path не может быть прочитан"; 
    exit(); 
}

$file = fread($fp, filesize($path)); 
fclose($fp);

$boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time())); // генерируем разделитель

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$headers .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\n";

$multipart = "--$boundary\n";

//$kod = 'koi8-r'; // или $kod = 'windows-1251'; 
$kod = 'utf8';
$multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=$kod\n"; 
$multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printed\n\n"; 
$multipart .= "$html\n\n";

$message_part = "--$boundary\n"; 
$message_part .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n"; 
$message_part .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; 
$message_part .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = \"".basename    ($path)."\"\n\n"; 
$message_part .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file))."\n";

$multipart .= $message_part."--$boundary--\n";

if(!mail($to, $thm, $multipart, $headers)) 
{
echo "К сожалению, письмо не отправлено"; 
exit(); 
}
}
```

Нужно добавить From $user_email и Return-path: $user_email, но ни в какую у меня не выходит. Как это правильно сделать?

UPD:
теперь выкладываю лог апача:

> [Mon May 14 13:22:08 2012] [error]
> [client 127.0.0.1] sendmail: Error
> during delivery: Message was not
> accepted -- it contains invalid
> headers.  More specially, 'From:'
> header must m, referer:
> http://lessons.loc/mail/registration.html
> [Mon May 14 13:23:14 2012] [warn]
> [client 127.0.0.1] mod_include:
> Options +Includes (or IncludesNoExec)
> wasn't set, INCLUDES filter removed
> [Mon May 14 13:23:25 2012] [error]
> [client 127.0.0.1] sendmail: Error
> during delivery: Message was not
> accepted -- it contains invalid
> headers.  More specially, 'From:'
> header must m, referer:
> http://lessons.loc/mail/registration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$headers .= "From: " . $from_email . "\n";
```

Вот это ^ вставьте после Вашего

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
```

Comment: $headers  ="MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
//$headers .="From: myemail@mail.ru\r\n";
$headers .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\n"; хоть тресни, если расскоментирую в лог ошибку пишет: [Mon May 14 14:21:27 2012] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_include: Options +Includes (or IncludesNoExec) wasn't set, INCLUDES filter removed, referer: http://lessons.loc/mail/registration.html

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждение, и уже не касающееся почты (оно от mod_include воообще, а не от sendmail).